# Is the statement "$(m, n)=d$ if and only if there exist integers $r$ and $s$ such that $r m+s n=d$" problematic?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

My textbook *Groups, Matrices, and Vector Spaces - A Group Theoretic Approach to Linear Algebra* by James B. Carrell said that

[image]

> $(m, n)=d$ if and only if there exist integers $r$ and $s$ such that $r m+s n=d$.

We have $2\cdot3+4\cdot5=26$, but $(3,5)=1\neq 26$. Could you please explain if this paragraph is problematic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first implication says there exists such two integers, not saying that any two integers you pick will fit the bill. For the case of (3,5) we can find 7*3+(-4)*5=1. So there exists integers. Now I notice the if and only if, so the reverse implication also must hold. It looks problematic like this. You are right. By this definition if d is gcd, than any multiple of d will also be gcd, which is wrong. The correct statement will be d, the smallest positive number for which there exists such two r and s will be gcd.

In other words d will be gcd if it is a positive generator for the ideal generated by m and n.

Comment: I agree that OP is right and the book is wrong. I suspect that Carrell intended $d$ to stand for positive integers dividing both $m$ and $n$. Among **such** integers, the gcd is the only one that can be expressed in the form $rm+sn$ with integers $r$ and $s$.  But if that was the intention, it should have been made clear.

Answer (score 3):

While true for $d=26$, the 'if and only if' bit means that if we *can* find a solution to $rm+sn=d$ for some positive integer $d$, and this $d$ is smaller than all the others, then this is the value of $(m,n)$, and in the case $(3,5)$ we have $2\cdot3+(-1)\cdot5=1$.

Comment: What do you mean by "While true for $d=26$"?

Comment: You can find solutions for any $d$ in this case because $(3,5)=1$. The statement asks you to find the smallest such $d$

Comment: You meant in our particular case, the smallest of such $d$ is 1?

Comment: It's also true for $d=341$ for example. For say $8$ and $12$, the smallest $d$ will be $4$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your clarification!